# How to add dynamic parameters to the Chef's node?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have an infrastructure under Chef's control with a lot of servers deploys each day. I need to add some dynamic data to each node based on user info, like:

```
user_data:
  first_name: aaa
  last_name: bbb
  department: ccc
```

`knife node edit` doesn't look like what I need, as I would prefer not to parse file on the fly, only add (and rewrite) single parameter structure.

**edit:**
This plugin seems to be quite good, if there are no native way: https://github.com/amian84/knife-set-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using tags?

- http://docs.opscode.com/dsl_recipe_method_tag.html
- http://docs.opscode.com/knife_tag.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to manage users on the machines dynamically you can try using the [chef-user cookbook](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-user).  You can set up users as data bags with a few attributes and include the chef-user cookbook in yours adding the users along with all their attributes.

If you have really custom data that you need to manipulate you can create your own data bag with whatever structure you want and then use the [search function](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_search.html) from within your recipe.  This will let you upload whatever data you want to query and pull it in to your recipe when you call it.

Although there are means to populate node attributes on the fly the "better" way to provide dynamic data to a chef run would be through the use of data bags.